# longtable width expands at random

Tags: longtable

I am using the longtable package to generate tables that may extend past a single page, and I am coming up with a strange format on particular tables.  The table itself looks like this:
[image: Picture of table generated]

And here is the code I used to generate it:

```
\begin{longtable}{| l | l || r |} 
\hline
\emph{Tag} & \emph{Name} & \emph{Percent Complete} \\
\hline

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 100.0\% \\ 
aaaaaa & bbbbbbb & 50.0\% \\ 
aaaaaa & bbbbbbb & 50.0\% \\ 
aaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & 0.0\% \\ 
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

So why is the width of the table suddenly expanded to the right about 3/4 of the way down? Am I missing something, or is there something that isn't being formatted correctly?

Comment: Your fonts are low-res :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's as expected, just re-run LaTeX until it stops asking you to re-run and everything will be OK, I promise:-)

Comment: The problem is this is scripted and uses pdflatex - I'm not sure if I can detect when a re-run is needed or not.

Comment: @nuclearpenguin: I would just add a couple of recompiles by default then and not worry about detection. There's also [`latexmk`](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) for this.

Comment: Adding a second recompile does seem to fix the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: well you can run it 2 or three times anyway or you can grep for "rerun latex" in the log file or you can save the log file from the last run and re-run until the log file shows no diff or...